# What is the meaning of t="array" for a formula element

Tags: arrays, excel, openxml, formula, xlsx

Currently I am analyzing `sheet1.xml` file extracted from a Excel 2007 .XLSX file. I find the following entry:

`<c r="D2" s="3"><f t="array" ref="D2">A2:A3+B2:C3</f><v>0.30000000000000004</v></c>`

What is the meaning of `t="array" ref="D2"` property in `<f>` element?

Thanks

Alan

Comment: Guesswork tells me that the formula is an array formula in cell D2. Array formulas are those which requires Ctrl+Shift+Enter to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

[ECMA-376](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm) Part 1 Section 18.3.1.40 on `<f>` (formula) says:

> array (Array formula)
>
> Array formula. An array formula is a single formula, applied across a range of one or more cells. An array formula can return multiple results from one single calculation, the results spanning the cells in which it is contained

The `ref` is the range to which the array formula applies. In this case 1 cell.

Answer (score 0):

`t="array"` indicates that the formula is an array formula (the type you get when you use control+shift+enter) and `ref="D2"` indicates that the formula only applies to D2.